# Vcard module in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

Is there a drupal module which imports the details of the Vcard and publish its detail in a user profile? Or any module which extracts details from a Vcard.

Thank you

Comment: Should be moved to drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vCard module from drupal.org (https://drupal.org/project/vcard) to auto create vCards depending on the details entered by each user.